# microsoft custom app manifest dont validate after clone

Tags: node.js, json, gulp, microsoft-teams

I have built a microsoft custom app with yo builder for microsoft teams and works fine, as I have uploaded into microsoft teams and test it. In addition, I push it on github. But when I clone the repo in a server in order to start deployment process, I get an error message as you can see on the uploaded image, when I try to run it with both gulp serve or gulp ngrok-serve. [image]

My manifest.json is as follow:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.11/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.11",
  "id": "{{APPLICATION_ID}}",
  "version": "{{VERSION}}",
  "packageName": "{{PACKAGE_NAME}}",
  "developer": {
    "name": "christos.goulas",
    "websiteUrl": "https://{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}",
    "privacyUrl": "https://{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}/privacy.html",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}/tou.html"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "tempbot02",
    "full": "tempbot02"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "TODO: add short description here",
    "full": "TODO: add full description here"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "icon-outline.png",
    "color": "icon-color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#D85028",
  "configurableTabs": [],
  "staticTabs": [],
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "{{MICROSOFT_APP_ID}}",
      "needsChannelSelector": true,
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "scopes": [
        "team",
        "personal",
        "groupchat"
      ],
      "commandLists": [
        {
          "scopes": [
            "team",
            "personal"
          ],
          "commands": [
            {
              "title": "Help",
              "description": "Shows help information"
            },
            {
              "title": "Who am I?",
              "description": "Shows information about your Teams user"
            },
            {
              "title": "Mention me",
              "description": "Let the bot @mention you"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "connectors": [],
  "composeExtensions": [],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "{{PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}}"
  ],
  "showLoadingIndicator": false
}
```

Comment: Looks like your manifest file has some invalid contents.
Please verify manifest using App Studio or Apps Validator: https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/appvalidation.html

Comment: @christos - Could you please confirm if the above suggestion helped you in any way or are you still facing the issue?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT My bad sorry. Yes indeed the manifest was not in a proper form. I changed some values I verified and worked

Answer (score 0):

Adding from comment section for more visibility

There was misconfiguration in manifest.